# Footer is not getting fixed at its position with custom class

Tags: html, css

i am trying to fix the position of the footer at the bottom of the page.
following is the code of css

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

but it is not working but when i use id for these properties it works.

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Question is why i am not able to use class for fixing the position of the footer in the bottom of the page. Are these some rules for these properties. Please advise.

Here is the html code for the above css

```
<div class="footerBar" style="">
    <label class="control-label" style="color: white">Copyright 2007-2017 </label>
    <label class="control-label" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;font-weight: bold;color: white">{{version}}</label>

</div>
```

and i am using the div in another div as follow

```
<div id="footer"><!-- calling of class for footer doesn't work for me here -->
    <footer-outlet></footer-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the link?

Comment: As per your html you should use `.footerBar` instead of `.footer`

Comment: Maybe there are some other css rules that overload the class rule? Did you try to see how properties are evaluated with some browser development console?

Comment: all check. my question is the above scenario is working with #id but not with .class. i am bit confused .

Answer (score 1):

try with snippet both are working fine

```css
.footer {
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <footer-outlet></footer-outlet>
</div>
```

width `ID`

```css
#footer {
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <footer-outlet></footer-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your input. in case of .class not working at my end , but id works

Comment: are you working with angular. can you provide a demo link ?

Comment: #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;

}
--------------------------------
.footerBar{

  /*width: 400px;*/
  height: 25px;
  width: 95%;
  mrgin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  /*margin: 0px;*/
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  /*z-index: 1000;*/
  /*margin-left: 65px;*/
  /*margin-right: 15px;*/
}
---------------------------------------
<div id="footer">
        <footer-outlet></footer-outlet>
    </div>

Comment: and here is the actual footer body
<div class="footerBar" style="">
        <label class="control-label" style="color: white">Copyright 2007-2017  </label>
        <label class="control-label" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;font-weight: bold;color: white">{{version}}</label>
       
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

As I can see issue is in class name, use `footerBar` instead of `footer`

```css
body{
  height:800px;
}
.footerBar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerBar">
  <label class="control-label" style="color: white">Copyright 2007-2017</label>
  <label class="control-label" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;font-weight: bold;color: white">{{version}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you are *not* making use of correct `class` in your html, which has the `style` in the `css`.
It is due to this, the styles in the footer doesn't gets applied.

**Error:** Using `footerBar` in the html.

**Correction:** *(either of the two)*

1. Use `.footer` in the `html`, that has the styles properties in the CSS.
2. Modify the class in the CSS with `.footerBar`, so that it represents the same as that of the html.

*Reason why `id` was working?*

The `id` was working because you have represented both in html and css with the same and correct `id` name.

Refer to the [*link*](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/1daw8smu/), where it works well.